# I need perticular regular expression for my data check

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I am very much new in regular expression.
I have only allow the users who will only input this type of data.

1. the string must start with w or W.
2. The string must have minimum two "/".
3. The string must have some character or number after any /.
4. after second / there should be minimum one number.

Please help me out. It is really stucking into for 2-3 hours.

Comment: So what did you try in those 2-3 hours?

Comment: ^[wW][A-Za-z0-9]*?\/[A-Za-z0-9]*?\/[0-9]*?$.. i tried this.. but it is allowing  taking nothing between // and after /. everything is working fine.

Comment: @user3454831 could you provide an example of the types of input that are acceptable?

Comment: w(then any character or number)/(not null)(any char or number)/(notnull)(minimum one number)(only numbers are allowed).

Comment: ex: w1//01 not allowed. after slash there should be something.

Comment: w1/2a/2 or wa/sdf/21 or w23a/we2/123

Comment: What if there are more then two slashes? Or means rule 4 that: after the last slash ...

Comment: @user3454831: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit and update your question when giving additional info instead of answering in the comment section.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
^[wW][a-zA-Z0-9]*(\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*?\/\d[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

EDIT-
Allowing only digits after the second slash-

```
^[wW][a-zA-Z0-9]*(\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*?\/\d+$
```

demo [here](http://regex101.com/r/hY7iC6)

Comment: There's no need to escape `/` if you don't use `/` as delimiters.

Comment: @Robin Yep but this is just a modification of OP's regex. It was in the question's comments.

Comment: @user3454831 Your rule -4)after second / there should be minimum one number.

Comment: yes.. minimum one number and maximum any number sir characters are not allowed.

Comment: @user3454831 it seems to work for me. Check the demo

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
^(?i)w[a-z0-9]*(?:/[a-z0-9]+)+/(?=.*\d+)[a-z0-9]*$
```

If you want only digits after the last slash:

```
^(?i)w[a-z0-9]*(?:/[a-z0-9]+)+/\d+$
```

Comment: hey after last slash it should not allow the any character.

Comment: @user3454831: Do you mean you want only digit after the last slash?

Comment: yes... and after second / there should be minimum one number.

Comment: in your post i m not allowd to enter w1/2a/11 format.. see after second slash there should be character or number. but after secondslash only numbers are allowed.

Comment: @user3454831: It works fine for me. How do you use it? And could you give some sample inputs? Edit your question for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

^[wW]+([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?(/[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+(/)+([0-9]+)$

As far as in understand the user just wants numbers after the second /

edited the regex

Comment: `\w` includes `_` that is not wanted.

Comment: @user3454831 i have edited the regex and now it can accept the format you asked. Let me know if it works

Comment: ^[wW]([A-Za-z0-9]?)+(/[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+(/)+([0-9]+)$ is the regex i am facing some issue in commenting it aboive

Answer (score 0):

```
(?i)w.*/[^/]+/[^/]*[0-9]+.*
```

Try this you can test [here](http://www.regexr.com/)